# How to overcome the numerical problem in the Schur complement to update inverse matrices

Tags: r, matrix, precision, numeric

I'm using the Schur complement (`d` in my code below) to update a matrix inverse. Suppose that I have square inversible matrix `A` of dimension `n-1` and its inverse is `A.inverse`, then I add one dimension in the matrix `A` obtaining `new.A`, now by Schur Complement I obtain the `new.inverse` using `A.inverse` and `new.A`. The code is presented below:

```
new.inverse = function(A.inverse, new.A){ 
  n = dim(A.inverse)[1]
    sigma12 = new.A[1:n, n+1, drop=FALSE]
    sigma21 = new.A[n+1, 1:n, drop=FALSE]
    sigma22 = new.A[n+1, n+1, drop=FALSE]
    d = (sigma22 - sigma21 %*% A.inverse %*% sigma12)^(-1)
    a = A.inverse + A.inverse %*% sigma12 %*% d %*% sigma21 %*% A.inverse
    b = - A.inverse %*% sigma12 %*% d
    c = - d %*% sigma21 %*% A.inverse
    return(rbind(cbind(a, b), c(c, d)))
}
```

The Schur complmenet is an exact calculation form (not an approximation), e.g. `solve(new.A) = new.inverse(A.inverse, new.A)`, but when I use this formula many times in a loop (1000 approximately), the `new.inverse(A.inverse, new.A)` diverges from `solve(new.A)`. An hint on how can I overcome this numerical issue?

Problem example:

```
xx=5*runif(2)+0 #x coordinates
yy=5*runif(2)+0 #y coordinates 
npoints = cbind(xx,yy)
distmatN = as.matrix(dist(npoints, method = "euclidean", upper=TRUE))
cov0 = exp(-distmatN)
inv.cov0 = solve(cov0)
res=vector()
for(i in 1:700){
  xx_new = 5*runif(1)+0; yy_new = 5*runif(1)+0; new_point = cbind(xx_new,yy_new) #creating the new point
  distmatNN = as.matrix(dist(rbind(npoints,new_point), method = "euclidean", upper=F)) #creating the new matrix distance with the new point
  cov_new = exp(-distmatNN)
  npoints = rbind(npoints,new_point, deparse.level = 0)
  cov0 = cov_new
  inv.cov0 = inverse.update.in(inv.cov0, cov0) 
  res[i] = max(abs(inv.cov0 - solve(cov0)))
}#;res
summary(res)
```

The value of `res` should be really small, but it is increasing.

Comment: Can you give an example matrix where the loop diverges?

Comment: @otwtm I added an example